# Jade to HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, npm, pug

I have this jade code that I would like to translate into HTML.  I think I have most of it but I can't figure out the hover part.

And for the Jade that I am trying to convert into HTML:
http://codepen.io/jzhang172/pen/Nqevge

My attempt:
http://codepen.io/jzhang172/pen/zGydZv

```css
*{
 transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.container{
 position: absolute;
 transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
}
.block
{
 height: 100px;
 line-height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
 .block .citation
{
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 35px;
}
 .block .author
{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #838eca;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 35px;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.third
{
 position: relative;
}
.third .citation{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
 .third .author
{
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
 .third .author:hover .citation
{
   transform: translateX(-70px);
    }
 .third .author:hover .author{
   right: -50px;
   opacity: 1;
   color: #ea8273;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class ="block third">
    <p class="citation">"Guess what. A quote."</p>
  <p class="author"> - and the author -
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking what the difference between the HTML/CSS that you wrote by hand and the HTML/CSS that you get if you **click on the View Compiled** button on the codepen link you provided is? (a) You need to provide the code *in the question itself* and (b) Use a diff tool.

Answer (score 0):

Jade has a built-in tool that does this

Just do :

jade "filename.jade" in the folder of your file and it will render a .html file.